# MySQL Aggregate Function with group by and join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have the following tables schemas and I want to get the sum of amount column for each category and the count of employees in the corresponding categories.

**employee**

```
id | name | category
1  | SC   | G 1.2
2  | BK   | G 2.2
3  | LM   | G 2.2
```

**payroll_histories**

```
id | employee_id | amount
1  | 1           | 1000
2  | 1           | 500
3  | 2           | 200
4  | 2           | 100
5  | 3           | 300
```

**Output table** should look like this:

```
category | total | count
G 1.2    | 1500  | 1
G 2.2    | 600   | 2
```

I have tried this query below its summing up and grouping but I cannot get the count to work.

```
SELECT 
  employee_id, 
  category, 
  SUM(amount) from  payroll_histories,employees   
WHERE employees.id=payroll_histories.employee_id 
GROUP BY category;
```

I have tried the `COUNT(category)` but that one too is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are, I believe, seeking two different summaries of your data. One is a sum of salaries by category, and the other is a count of employees, also by category.

You need to use, and then join, separate aggregate queries to get this.

```
SELECT a.category, a.amount, b.cnt
  FROM (
         SELECT e.category, SUM(p.amount) amount
           FROM employees e
           JOIN payroll_histories p ON e.id = p.employee_id
          GROUP BY e.category
       ) a
   JOIN (
          SELECT category, COUNT(*) cnt
            FROM employees
           GROUP BY category
        ) b ON a.category = b.category
```

The general principle here is to avoid trying to use just one aggregate query to aggregate more than one kind of detail entity. Your amount aggregates payroll totals, whereas your count aggregates employees.

Alternatively for your specific case, this query will also work. But it doesn't generalize well or necessary perform well.

```
 SELECT e.category, SUM(p.amount) amount, COUNT(DISTINCT e.id) cnt
   FROM employees e
   JOIN payroll_histories p ON e.id = p.employee_id
  GROUP BY e.category
```

The COUNT(DISTINCT....) will fix the combinatorial explosion that comes from the join.

(Pro tip: use the explicit join rather than the outmoded `table,table WHERE` form of the join. It's easier to read.)

Comment: Great explanation, I did not use the first one but the second one worked as expected. Can you dwell on the combinatorial explosion. Any good resource explaining this?